# Which operations create a minor of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I came across two definitions which operations are allowed to construct a minor
 from a given graph.

One definition allows edge contractions and edge deletions, the other additionally
 vertex deletions.

- Can any vertex deletion also be achieved by edge deletions and edge contractions ?
- If not, which definition is the proper one to recognize, for example, planar graphs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wikipedia page on [graph minors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) states "$H$ is called a minor of the graph $G$ if $H$ can be formed from $G$ by deleting edges and vertices and by contracting edges."

I'd say the deleting vertex part is mostly redundant, since you can effectively delete through edge deletions and contractions:  delete all of its edges except one, then contract along that final edge.  However, technically you can't get rid of an isolated vertex in this manner, so the vertex deletion is necessary in that rather trivial case.

Comment: But the procedure always works if the vertices are not isolated ? That would be enough for me because the case of isolated vertices is from no practical interest.

Comment: @Peter -- Yes, though you might have to be slightly careful you don't delete an edge that would cause a vertex to become isolated.

Comment: Thank you for your insights!